# Volume not getting mounted (Nexus is running on this Pod)

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

Nexus is running on worker node and Nexus UI went down because of storage issue. We increased the storage space from 150 GB to 210GB for PV & PVC.

Increased storage for PV and PVC

[image]

Then, when we tried to up the Nexus, volume is not getting mounted for nexus pod. Attached error message.

Comment: I'm not sure which error message from your picture (please don't paste pictures but the actual terminal output formatted with code tags) is the correct one. Apparently, the rbd image doesn't exist anymore. So does a resize just create a new rbd? This would mean that you need to attach a different volume. But I'm not familiar with k8s and pvc so I might be wrong.

Comment: expanding a rbd device doesn't create a new one. It doesn't make sense one could attach (`rbd map`) yet not mount (`mount`) a volume. Sounds like networking error (mtu? IP spoofing?). From the node where that volume is supposed to be attached, I would dig in: lsblk, try to mount partition from last /dev/rbd attached, copy in ceph.conf & keyring on that node, then rbd ls. dmesg should show an error for each failed mount attempt.